# SelectMany enumerating multiple files filtered by string value need index

Tags: c#, linq

I have a C# LINQ query that takes in many files and enumerates each file looking for 'risky strings'. When each file finds a 'risky string' I need to save the file name as a key into a dictionary and the line number it is found on which is saved to the dictionary value as an array (there will be multiple occurences of found 'risky strings' per file).  I cannot seem to figure out how to get line number from the query. Currently what it is doing is just starting at 0 and counting every time a string is found and saving to array not the actual line number itself.

Help!

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(srcPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(s => s.EndsWith(riskFileType))
                .SelectMany(File.ReadLines, (file, line) => new {file, line}).Distinct()
                .Where(@t => filterStringExpression.IsMatch(t.line))
                .Select((@t, index) => new {File = @t.file, Line = @t.line, index}).Distinct()
                .GroupBy(q => q.File)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(q => q.index)
                .ToArray());
```

Current output:

```
Namespace risk strings were found on the below classes, please review the results.
..\..\src\classes\BookingCls.cls risk found on lines:  0,  1,  2, 
..\..\src\classes\BookingDaySnapshotCls.cls risk found on lines:  3, 
..\..\src\classes\BookingEventCls.cls risk found on lines:  4,  5, 
..\..\src\classes\BookingOwnerChangeExt.cls risk found on lines:  6,  7,  8, 
..\..\src\classes\BookingSourceChangeExt.cls risk found on lines:  9,  10,  11, 
..\..\src\classes\GuestroomTypeDayCls.cls risk found on lines:  12,
```

Comment: I would recommend [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) as LINQ learning tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assign the line numbers when load files.

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(srcPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => s.EndsWith(riskFileType))
    .SelectMany(
        file => File.ReadLines(file).Select((line, index) => new {line, rowNumber = index + 1}), 
        (file, line) => new {file, line.line, line.rowNumber})
    .Where(@t => filterStringExpression.IsMatch(t.line))
    .GroupBy(q => q.file)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(q => q.rowNumber))
    .ToArray();
```

It is just alternative query:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(srcPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => s.EndsWith(riskFileType))
    .SelectMany(
        file => File.ReadLines(file).Select((line, index) => new {line, rowNumber = index + 1}), 
        (file, line) => new {file, line.line, line.rowNumber})
    .Where(@t => filterStringExpression.IsMatch(t.line))
    .ToLookup(k => k.file, e => e.rowNumber);
```

Comment: I like your idea here but i do not understand what the function of `Distinct` is. You have a sequence of (file, line, row) tuples; surely those will *all* be distinct, right? You won't ever have two of the same file, with the same line, at the same location.

Comment: You my friend are a gentleman and a scholar!  I have been stuck on this all day!  I am new to LINQ and am still learning the ropes and was not 100% sure what distinct did. Now that you explained that it makes more sense.  Everything works perfectly Thank you!

Comment: @Eric Lippert - you are right, thanks. Queries were fixed.